# Store unstructured JavaScript object in MongoDB with Mongoose+Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, javascript-objects

In my **node.js** app, I need to store unstructured JavaScript objects in **MongoDB**. I have specified following model in **Mongoose**:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('DBAllocation', {
    from: Date,
    expires: Date,
    userSession: Object,
    allocationTimestamp: Date,
    allocationPriority: Number,
    vmGroupID: String,
    allocationRequestContent: Object
});
```

By specifying the data types of `userSession` and `allocationRequestContent` to be type `Object`, I wanted to save a **JavaScript object (without specifying its structure)** into MongoDB and retrieve it as is. But when I save the model into database, I get an internal error. I tried to store following items:

```
var allocation = new Allocation({
                        _id: allocationID,
                        from: Date.now(),
                        expires: null,
                        userSession: authorizedRequest.session,
                        allocationTimestamp: Date.now(),
                        allocationPriority: <some number>,
                        vmGroupID: <some number>,
                        allocationRequestContent: authorizedRequest.requestContent
                    });
```

`authorizedRequest.session` and `authorizedRequest.requestContent` are two JavaScript Objects. But when I replace both of them with `{}`, model gets saved successfully. I have heard of `strict` parameter which we can use to store unstructured data, but I doubt whether I can use it to achive what I need. Is there a way to acomplish this anyway? Any help would be really appreciated.

**Update:**

I figured out that `authorizedRequest.session` is a MongoDB model and I replaced it with `authorizedRequest.session.toObject()` and replaced `authorizedRequest.requestContent` with a simple object such as {'cat': '123', 'dog':'456'} and it was saved successfully. Can't figure out what's going on.

`authorizedRequest.requestContent` includes following object.

```
{
        "group":[
            {
                "vm_count":[
                    "10"
                ],
                "image":[
                    {
                        "type":[
                            "iso"
                        ],
                        "id":[
                            "280b40d0-6644-4e47-ac7c-074e2fa40cd4"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "cpu":[
                    {
                        "cores":[
                            "1"
                        ],
                        "frequency":[
                            "1"
                        ],
                        "unit":[
                            "GHz"
                        ],
                        "architecture":[
                            "x86"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "min_memory":[
                    {
                        "size":[
                            "2"
                        ],
                        "unit":[
                            "GB"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "min_storage":[
                    {
                        "primary":[
                            "5"
                        ],
                        "unit":[
                            "GB"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "network":[
                    {
                        "min_bandwidth":[
                            "8"
                        ],
                        "unit":[
                            "mbps"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "priority":[
                    "3"
                ],
                "allocation_time":[
                    {
                        "schedule":[
                            {
                                "date":[
                                    {
                                        "$":{
                                            "year":"",
                                            "month":"",
                                            "date":""
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "time_from":[
                                    ""
                                ],
                                "time_to":[
                                    ""
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "session_id":[
            "3deb1bb861f34b527e6709c655fff139b36c2dc43d8b3e29e3914bf8b23ce069"
        ]
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Tried the Schema.Types.Mixed ( http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html ) ?

Comment: Yeah. But still does not work. It seems like only a simple object would be accepted. When the object itself contains nested objects, it gives an Internal Error.

Comment: Can you add the details of the error you're getting to your question?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I am not getting a detailed error! When debugging, I only get `Internal Error! Value is null`

Comment: @Deepal Based on your update, it seems that there's something in `authorizedRequest.requestContent` that can't be serialized into BSON so that it can be stored in the collection.  What does that contain?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, I updated my question including the content of `authorizedRequest.requestContent`. How can I identify whether it can be serialized into BSON?

Comment: @Deepal The problem is likely that `$` key, as `$` is a reserved character in MongoDB field names. You'll need to change that.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Wow. Thanks for pointing out that, you can include your comment as an answer so I can accept. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely the `$` key in the `authorizedRequest.requestContent` object as MongoDB field names can't start with a `$`.

See [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) for possible work-arounds.